# Sql Select using CTE to order a recursive data

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Please i want a solution for this problem using CTE in SQL Server

**Example for the situation**

```
Equation 0 = 0.25*Equation 1
Equation 1 = Equation 2 + Equation 3 + 0.5*Equation 5
Equation 2 = 15 + 40
Equation 3 = Equation 6 + Equation 7
Equation 4 = 10
Equation 5 = 10 + Equation 4
Equation 6 = 10 +5
Equation 7 = Equation 5 + Equation 2
```

The structure of the tables is

**The Element Table**

```
ID     | Name
-------|--------------
0      | Equation 0
1      | Equation 1
2      | Equation 2
3      | Equation 3
4      | Equation 4
5      | Equation 5
6      | Equation 6
7      | Equation 7
---------------------
```

the table holds all items of each equation

**The equation Table**

```
FK     |    Item   |    Type
-------|-----------|------------------
0      |    0.25   |    constant
0      |    *      |    Operator
0      |    1      |    Element
1      |    2      |    Element
1      |    +      |    Operator
1      |    3      |    Element
1      |    +      |    Operator
1      |    0.5    |    constant
1      |    *      |    Operator
1      |    5      |    Element
2      |    15     |    constant
2      |    +      |    Operator
2      |    40     |    constant
…      |           |      
…      |           | 
… etc  |           |        
------------------------------------
```

if the type is element this means it is an element item

is there any sql statement result to the correct order that i must use to calculate these equations one by one without using recursive functions because it is limited in SQL 
the alternative is to calculate the last equation without any requirements then calculate the upper ones as when i need an equation i find it calculated already without recursing the equations

i need the sql select statement to produce the following order

```
Equation 2
Equation 6
Equation 4
Equation 5
Equation 7
Equation 3
Equation 1
Equation 0
```

i ordered them by eye because it is simple example 
is there any select statement is used to do so
or the user must order them manually ???

---

- ***... Update***

  ***1. with a fully working test scenario***

***The Script to create tables***

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Element]    Script Date: 26/03/2017 11:10:10 م ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Element](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Element] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Equation]    Script Date: 26/03/2017 11:10:10 م ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Equation](
    [fk] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Item] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Element] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (0, N'Equation 0')
INSERT [dbo].[Element] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'Equation 1')
INSERT [dbo].[Element] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'Equation 2')
INSERT [dbo].[Element] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (3, N'Equation 3')
INSERT [dbo].[Element] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (4, N'Equation 4')
INSERT [dbo].[Element] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (5, N'Equation 5')
INSERT [dbo].[Element] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (6, N'Equation 6')
INSERT [dbo].[Element] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (7, N'Equation 7')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (0, N'0.25', N'constant')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (0, N'*', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (0, N'1', N'Element')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (1, N'2', N'Element')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (1, N'+', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (1, N'3', N'Element')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (1, N'+', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (1, N'0.5', N'constant')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (1, N'*', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (1, N'5', N'Element')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (2, N'15', N'constant')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (2, N'+', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (2, N'40', N'constant')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (3, N'6', N'Element')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (3, N'+', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (3, N'7', N'Element')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (4, N'10', N'Constant')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (5, N'10', N'Constant')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (5, N'+', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (5, N'4', N'Element')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (6, N'10', N'Constant')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (6, N'+', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (6, N'5', N'Constant')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (7, N'5', N'Element')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (7, N'+', N'Operator')
INSERT [dbo].[Equation] ([fk], [Item], [Type]) VALUES (7, N'2', N'Element')
```

---

2. *

> @Gordon Linoff

- ... Thanks a lot for your care but i found some errors using the provided script that i cant solve as it is the first time for me to use CTE

The second script gives me some errors that i cant solve
[image]

the first script gives me errors as well that i cant solve
[image]

Comment: why must be a cte solution?

Comment: because the data is recursive

Comment: where is the order on equation table?

Comment: no need for it it is saved as entered

Comment: then selected as saved

Comment: Can you plz explain once more ?you want to order table Element table in given order.is there any other criteria for ordering.How ordering of element table related with Equation table.Now after I have down ordering then what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
WITH Related AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Equation AS eq
    LEFT JOIN Element AS e ON eq.[Type]='Element' AND eq.Item=CAST(e.Id AS VARCHAR(10))
    WHERE eq.[Type]='Element' 
)
,Dependecies AS
(
    SELECT e.*
          ,ISNULL(r.Name,'') AS DepName 
    FROM Element AS e
    LEFT JOIN Related AS r ON e.Id=r.fk
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS lvl,d.Id,d.Name,d.DepName
    FROM Dependecies AS d
    WHERE d.Name NOT IN(SELECT x.DepName FROM Dependecies AS x)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.lvl+1,d.Id,d.Name,d.DepName
    FROM recCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN Dependecies AS d ON r.DepName=d.Name

)
,Ranked AS
(
    SELECT Name
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN DepName='' THEN 1000 ELSE lvl END DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM recCTE
)
SELECT Name,MIN(Rnk) AS Rnk
FROM Ranked
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Min(Rnk)
```

The result

```
Equation 2  1
Equation 4  1
Equation 6  1
Equation 5  2
Equation 7  3
Equation 3  4
Equation 1  5
Equation 0  6
```

### Explanation

There is a list of CTEs:

- The first CTE will bind the Elements to Equation rows, where the type is `Element`.
- The second will list all Elements with their dependencies
- The third CTE is a recursive CTE, starting with the element without any dependecies, working down the dependency path
- The next CTE uses `DENSE_RANK() OVER()` to get the calls ordered

The final `SELECT` returns each element and the earliest moment it is needed.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and for the explanation of the script as well

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it would be swell if we could express this as:

```
with cte as (
      select e.fk, 1 as lev
      from equation e
      group by e.fk
      having sum(case when type = 'Element' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
      union all
      select e.fk, max(cte.lev) + 1
      from equation e left join
           cte
           on e.fk = cte.fk
      group by e.fk
      having count(*) = count(cte.fk)
     )
```

But that is not possible.  So, we have to think in terms of string manipulation (I think).  This results in putting the dependencies in a string and repeatedly chopping elements off of the string.  If I have this right:

```
with eq as (
       select e.fk,
              stuff( (select ',' + e2.item
                      from equation e2
                      where e2.fk = e.fk and e2.type = 'Element'
                      order by e2.item
                      for xml path ('')
                     ), 1, 1, '') as elements 
       from (select distinct e.fk from equation e) e
      )
      select e.fk, '' as elements_found, 1 as lev
      from eq
      where elements = ''
      union all
      select eq.fk, substring(elements_found, charindex(',', elements_found + ',') + 1), 2 as lev
      from eq join
           cte
           on cte.elements_found like eq.fk + ',%' and eq.fk = cte.fk
      where eq.type = 'Element'
     )
select cte.fk, max(lev)
from cte
group by cte.fk
order by max(lev);
```

Comment: hello thanks a lot but i found errors that i cant solve could you please help me the error and the script for creating my table is in the upper answer